# What are the android features that OpenTok use?

Tags: android, opentok

I have a problem with running app on **android thing**.It works find on normal android.The app is using opentok that I use for making a call and chat.

I have look up the android thing doc about the platform differences
https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/platform-differences

I tried to search about the features that they use,but there is none.

Is opentok using any of these features?

Comment: Do you request `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?, What's an android thing?, Which version of Android is it running?, What is not working of Opentok?